# How to output latest created file in shell

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have an executable which creates either `file1` or `file2` along with other files. I am trying to write a shell script which should output the latest created file. If the executable creates `file1`, the output should be `file1`. Please note that I already have both `file1` and `file2` exists in the directory along with other files. The executable overwrites it.
If there are no file1/file2 exist, below script works but this doesn't work if both `file1` and `file2` exists.

```
if [ -e "file1" ]; then
   output="file1"
else
   output="file2"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

- [Sourced mostly from this stack post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885934/bash-function-to-find-newest-file-matching-pattern)

The quick and easy way.

```
output="$(ls -td control.tk input.scs 2> /dev/null|head -1)"
```

However I would only use this if you can make sure that the files don't contain funny characters like newlines or spaces. If you can guarantee that the filenames do not contain funny characters then parsing `ls` is quite safe.

- [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- [How can I find the latest (newest, earliest, oldest) file in a directory?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003)

Comment: Thanks Zachary. My files names are "input.scs" & "control.tk".

Comment: @kumar Then the above should work fine for you.

Comment: Also my executable creates several other files which I am not interested. I want to output either input.scs or control.tk based on when it is created.

Comment: @kumar checkout the updated answer.